# SQLAlchemy: How to get grandchild attributes from grandparent?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Each `League` has many seasons, and each `Season` has many teams, and each `Team` table has a `goals_for` column.

Suppose I want to count all `goals_for` all teams in **one** league, across **all** seasons. But I'm stuck at even accessing the teams from within seasons.

The following returns an item of type League:

```
get_teams_for_leagues = League.query.join(League.seasons).join(Season.teams).all()
print(get_teams_for_leagues)
```

How can I access `teams` from `League`?

```
class League(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    # One side of many to one with Season
    seasons = relationship("Season", back_populates="league", lazy='joined')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<League %r>' % (self.full_name)

class Season(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    season_string_form = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    # Many side of many to one wih Season
    league_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('league.id'))
    league = relationship("League", back_populates="seasons")

    # One side of many to one with Team
    teams = relationship("Team", back_populates="season")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Season %r>' % (self.id)


class Team(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    goals_for = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # Many side of many to one with Season
    season_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('season.id'))
    season = relationship("Season", back_populates="teams")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Team %r>' % (self.name)
```

Comment: What does your model look like? Please add the code for it.

Comment: @MrLeeh Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just do an aggregation, something like:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

res = db_session.query(func.sum(Team.goals_for), Team.name)\
         .join(Season).join(League)\
         .filter(League.full_name = 'La Liga')\
         .group_by(Team.name).all()
```